# How to combine URLs when the iframe inside of a mainframe changes

Tags: hyperlink, iframe

How can I create a URL that will take a user to a specific iframe inside of a mainframe when not originally in the mainframe site?

For example, if I have 3 iframes of images on my site and I want to share one of the images with another user, is there a way I can create a URL so that the person I share the URL will go to the specific iframe I choose?

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript and just set `my_iframe_elem.src = "http://www.example.com";`